# Change images dimensions - Error at massively import - Prestashop 1.7

Tags: image, csv, import, prestashop

I have observed abnormal behavior in my shop when bulk importing or uploading images through the backend. The images are filled in white to a certain size.

To solve that I have changed the size parameters in the image "product_default" in Design> Image settings.

When I did this, the uploaded image was displayed correctly, but when I clicked to display in full size, it was completely distorted.

I attach some explanatory screenshots.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: in preferences > images, you can regenerate all images

Comment: Thanks Melvita, but there isn't the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** SOLVED **

The solution I was found was change all dimension for all the images to preserve te square relation.